# Play audio in inactive tab with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I write a web chat using Websocket.
Problem is user switch browser's tabs and I want to play a sound to let them know that someone want to talk to him in chat's tab.

I saw FaceBook and GMail can play a 'ping' once their chat have new message in inactive tab.

How do they do it with JavaScript or there are any solutions?

Comment: Is this really just a general question about how to play a sound file in Javascript? Because it seems like that's all you need to do here (triggering the sound when a chat message is received of course)...

Comment: I think the question here is to play sound only when the chat is NOT in the active tab.

Answer (score 5):

How's this?

```
function beep(file,volume){
    var snd = new Audio(file);
    volume = volume ? volume : 0.5; // defaults to 50% volume level
    snd.volume = volume;

    // LISTENER: Rewind the playhead when play has ended
    snd.addEventListener('ended',function(){
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime=0;
    });

    // Play the sound
    snd.play();
}

beep("audioFiles/beep.mp3", 1.0);
```